Need help in running ASP.NET Core Web API in Docker Container
I am new to Docker. I have installed DockerDesktop. I am trying to expose an ASP.NET Core Web API via docker containers.
This is my docker file:
# This stage is used to build the service project
FROM *****/dotnet-80-sdk-runtime:latest AS builder #local artificatory within my company
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /build
USER root
COPY ./NuGet.Config ./NuGet.Config 
COPY . .
RUN ls -la
RUN dotnet restore "./GrafProm.API.csproj" --configfile ./NuGet.Config
RUN dotnet build "./GrafProm.API.csproj" -c Release --no-restore -o /app/buildOutput
RUN dotnet publish "./GrafProm.API.csproj" -c Release --no-restore -o /app/publish

FROM *****/dotnet-80-runtime:latest AS run
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
ENV DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/mware/dotnet
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=development
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/containers
#
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GrafProm.API.dll"]

I am using VS 2022 and this is my launchsettings.json file:
 "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5293"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Container (Dockerfile)": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": false
    }

When I run the container (Dockerfile) in VS, the image and container are getting created, but I get this error:

Instead of getting swagger page, I am getting an error page in IE.
Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

Hi user1447718，may I know if the project copy from other machine or download from some where ? If yes, please try to remove and re-add the docker support, then try again.

@JasonPan no , i didnt download the project from anywhere... i created it manually in my localbox. thanks.

How about using other sdk runtime? Instead of FROM *****/dotnet-80-sdk-runtime:latest AS builder #local artificatory within my company. I mean we can test it to verify the issue is related to image or not.

when i build it from command promot using below commands docker build -t grafprom.api.img . docker run --rm -p8081:8080 grafprom.api.img:latest, it worked when i entered the url http://localhost:8081/swagger/index.html in browser.  which is expected.  but when i run it from visual studio docker shortcut, that's when am facing this issue...

Hi user1447718, I understand your previous attempts to use the command line to work well with your company's own image. However, I still insist that you use Microsoft's official image for testing to see if you encounter the same error.

Because I want to prove that it seems that there may be a potential problem with VS2022 for self-hosted images through the normal use of the official image. What I mean is that it seems that the configuration somewhere caused all this. If it is verified that the official image is fine, then we can add the vs2022 tag or raise a new issue on MS DC Fourm.
